# How to add some variables to Django Admin index.html

Tags: django, django-admin

I Want to show objects from a model in a custom list in the Django Admin index.html.

I have the custom `templates/admin/index.html`, but i can't find a way to override the variables that go to index.html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: too broad question: about what variables are you talking about? there are so many variables in index.html to override..

Comment: I have a model Messages that have a field destinator as User Foreign Key, and I want to show a messages list for the user in the index.

Comment: I know how to override the add_view, change_list view, etc for the apps in the admin, but not how to override the index view to send the queryset to the template  `templates/admin/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

You could override/subclass the appropriate functions or classes from the admin package. Or, depending on what variables you need to pass, you could [drop them in as extra option kwargs in the url pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) where you include the admin urls.